# Востановление Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование, файловая-система

Такая проблема: есть бэкап архив со всеми корневыми папками Ubuntu и есть установленная Ubuntu рядом с Windows7. Какие папки/файлы не нужно трогать(`/dev`, `/etc`, ...) при замене из бэкапа, чтобы восстановить, но и Linux с Windows в связке работали? Сталкивался кто-нибудь с таким?

Comment: `/dev`, `/sys`, `/proc` - это виртуальные каталоги. Там на самом деле ничего нет. Оно генерится при загрузке. Если бэкап именно этой системы - просто разверни что есть. Максимум - сделай ещё раз `sudo update-grub`.